# Conditional NuGet PackageReference in csproj without Multi-Targeting

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, nuget, .net-standard

I have a `Xamarin.Forms` project targeting `iOS` and `Android`. In a shared `netstandard` library which is referenced by the iOS and Android project i would like to use a specific NuGet `PackageReference` based on the on the platform the library is referenced by. The problem is that because of my project structure i cannot multi-target the `netstandard` project - is there a way to achieve such a scenario without adding multiple `TargetFrameworks` to the head project?

Could this condition be done with custom configurations i.e. `Debug | iOS` or `Debug | Droid`

Comment: "because of my project structure i cannot multi-target" not possible at all ?

Comment: thanks for the reply. unfortunately multi-targeting is not feasible in this case